# how to intruduce a traffic Flows using real life data in Sumo

Tags: sumo, traffic-simulation

how can i use real life data to define traffic distribution in sumo

I would like to build a real scenario using real road network and real traffic data.

how can I use that data to generate traffic to be used in the scenario?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The SUMO documentation is quite extensive on the topic of demand generation: https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Demand/Introduction_to_demand_modelling_in_SUMO.html There really lots of possibilities depending on the data you have.